How to check if a particular stock is open to trading using Yfinance
I am using yfinance.download() to store stock information but I don't want it to include a stock's most recent day's statistics if that data is still changing (i.e. the market or markets the stock is listed on are still open). Is there any way to check if a particular stock is currently being traded using Python (preferably with the yfinance API)?
I thought about checking to see if the stock's dataframe (returned by yf.download()) changes after a short delay between downloads, but I don't think this will be effective for stocks with few daily trades.
Similar questions were already posted but they talk about checking if specific exchanges are open (stocks can be dual listed) and they don't use yfinance's API.

ideally you want to get the exchange's trading calendar, the tradinghours module is probably the best around but it costs $$$, else you'll need to scrape exchange sites for those , build your own calendar - most trading hours are pretty stablem, just holidays/half-days to deal with. or only collect todays data tomorrow !  https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/ may be worth a look
